# Removing whole method by regexp

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I'm cleaning my codebase, and I'm wondering if i can use Eclipse regexp to remove (replace) all logging related stuff.

Example code:

```
public static void setFoo( Foo param ) {
    singleton.setBar(param);
}

private void log(String msg) {
    Logger.log( msg );
}

private void setBar( Foo param ) {
    log( "Foo: " 
        + param.toString() );
    log( "bar" );
    this.mParam = param;
}
```

Each class have it's own private `log(String msg)` method which needs to be removed as well as all references to these methods. I've looked tips and hints around the net and tried few examples with no success...

**Update:**

Search for single line log() -references works with `^.*{1}\Wlog{1}\W.*\;\R`

`{1}\W` around `log` are for rejecting `Dialog`, `logo`, etc matches.

How to add multiline support? `(?s)` in the expression will cause match for all text in file before `log` -match...

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Using regexp to parse a grammar is always complicated, risky, and not guaranteed to fail (regexp cannot match all of what a grammar comprises). Try using java parsers.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But this is one shot task, and if i can remove almost all lines, handwork will be in rationale level... But i'll check java parsers too.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by removing all import statements for logging. The logging lines will then show up clearly as compile-time errors.

Comment: How this relates to regexp?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with one find/replace or refactoring operation across your codebase. The easiest way to do it is class by class:

1. remove the contents of the log method
2. select the method
3. select Refactor > Inline...

Comment: I think it is not impossible, but I'll be happy if someone can help me to build two (or more) separated regexps to clean my code by two search/replace run... 1. remove all log() -methods. 2. remove all (multiline) references.

Comment: Can't get absolute metrics now, but project contains more than one hundred classes. And about 80 % of those has logging.

Answer (score 0):

After slept night i finally got a solution...

1. All `log(String msg){}` methods can be removed by expression
   `(?s)^(\s|\w)*void\s{1}log{1}\W(.|^})*?[}](\s)*\R`. Works for method definitions as defined in the question.
2. All references can be removed by `(?s)^\s*log{1}\W(.|^;)*?[;](\s)*\R`. Matches to multiline method calls too.

Feel free to fix syntax if you see some violations, but those expressions seems to be quite robust for my needs.